# cd that manipulates only one part of the path at the beginning in Bash (like ZSH)

Tags: bash, filesystems

Is there any way to reproduce the behaviour of `cd` in the zsh shell in bash?

http://zshwiki.org/home/builtin/cd

The `cd` in Bash can also change some directories at some lower levels:

```
% pwd
~/data/foo/horrible/dir/names
% cd foo bar
% pwd
~/data/bar/horrible/dir/names
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `cd` that implements the functionality you want and then calls the builtin.

```
cd() {
  if (( $# == 2 )) && [[ "$1" != -* ]]
  then
    builtin cd "${PWD/$1/$2}"
  else
    builtin cd "$@"
  fi
}
```

Comment: How exaclty is that working? I think it has something to do with the {/} command. What is it doing?
Great pice of code!

Comment: `${PWD/$1/$2}` is search&replace, similar to `echo "$PWD" | sed "s/$1/$2/"`.

Comment: may I take your code and put it in my publicy available Bashrc? If yes, how should I give you credits? To your Stackoverflow Account?